# Is there any way to add a Listener for changes in battery level in react native (non-expo) application?

Tags: android, react-native, listener, batterylevel, react-native-cli

I am searching for a way where I can constantly listen to the changes in the battery level of the device in a non-expo react native application.

I have tried packages like 'react-native-device-info' and 'react-native-device-battery'. They provide the functionality to get the battery level of the device. But couldn't find a way to add a listener that constantly listens to the battery level.

I have explored some ways to add listeners to the react native application. But none of them seemed like standardized ways.

Comment: In Android, it isn't a good practice to constantly listen in on changes in the battery state. You can get notified when the battery state changes drastically [reference](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring#MonitorLevel).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Get battery status / level Using Native Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44920299/react-native-get-battery-status-level-using-native-modules)

Comment: @tomerpacific Thanks for the info, the purpose of the application I am building is to trigger an action when the battery level get's lower than a certain percentage. Is there any way I can do that without having a listener ?